# AngularのNgForOfのNgとは何の略でしょうか？

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

AngularのNgForOfのNgとは何の略でしょうか？

[NgForOf](https://angular.jp/api/common/NgForOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AngularJS / Miscellaneous/ FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) によると

> Why is this project called "AngularJS"? Why is the namespace called "ng"?
> Because HTML has angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "AngularJS".

A**ng**ular を表してるそうです

Answer (score 1):

@oriri さんの回答の追加情報として。

`ng`はAngularが自身用のディレクティブを示す接頭辞として予約しているそうですね。

[Directive custom prefix](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#directive-custom-prefix)

> **Don't** prefix a directive name with `ng` because that prefix is reserved for Angular and using it could cause bugs that are difficult to diagnose.

[NgForOf DIRECTIVE](https://angular.jp/api/common/NgForOf)